# Split Name into First name and Last Name Java (Android OCR)

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, ocr

I have create a OCR (Optical Character Recognition) application using Native Android JAVA. I can convert my image to text view. But how can I separately identify Firstname,Lastname,Email address using that words?
Can you give me the sample code for that process?

Example

**Jason Brave**

**JSON43@gmail.com**

In here **Jason is the Firstname**. **Brave is the second name** and **JSON43@gmail.com is the Email**.

Comment: Why a 2nd question?

Answer (score 1):

Do it something like this:

```
 String s = "Jason Brave JSON43@gmail.com";
 String[] split = s.split(" "); // split using whitespace
 String firstName = split[0];
 String lastName = split[1];
 String email = split[2];
```